# Getting data from Cognos (scripting)

Tags: php, visual-studio, excel, cognos

If someone can please tell me how I can get data from cognos automatically. It can be a script in php, or an application that can get a predifined report and save it in an excel file. Cognos can save in an excel file but the adress barr desn`t change (it uses tons of javascript).

Comment: So you're trying to render a COGNOS report via PHP? Why not just query the DB directly?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways you can programmatically orchestrate activities or retrieve data in Cognos

1. Cognos exposes a "URL" interface for some of the most common activities.  This includes running a report, viewing saved output, opening a report in report studio, etc.
2. You can use the Cognos SDK.  This is the most powerful way to orchestrate things in Cognos.  It has a large surface area and a fairly steep learning curve, but if you're willing to invest the time in it, the possibilities are endless
3. You can use the Cognos Mashup service - this is kind of like "SDK Lite".   Its much easier to use but exposes a much smaller surface area.   As the name implies, its useful for mashup type scenarios.

Here's an article which describes Cognos Mashup vs. Cognos SDK, and provides some heuristics for when you would choose one over the other :

http://www.motio.com/blog/2010/11/01/cognos-sdk-vs-cognos-mashup.do

Comment: lol, does cognos solve problem out of a box---(yes)--->Relax drink a beer

Answer (score 1):

Talking of an application - COGNOS has such features itself, you can schedule a report and save it in the file system which should meet your requirement.

If you are willing to use PHP then hitting the database directly (as suggested to you already) is a good idea.